# Automata, operation on languages

Tags: logic, automata, regular-language

I have some exercise to solve for my automata course at university. I cannot understand, however, what exactly $L_1L_2$ means for some languages $L_1$ and $L_2$. The problem is - prove that If $L_1\cup L_2 \subseteq L_3\cap L_4 => L_1L_2 \subseteq L_3L_4$ .
What is $L_1L_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language concatenation is defined as

$$L_1L_2 = \{ uv \mid u \in L_1, v \in L_2 \}$$

Comment: Thank youu ! :)